# XAML Passing Messages from another Element

Tags: xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a button where I'm trying to pass down to the ViewModel the ActualHeight/ActualWidth of the main grid on the control.  My XAML looks something like this:

```
  <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="47" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--  ROW 0  -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" />

            <Button
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                Margin="5,5,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                cm:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action LaunchMirrorView({Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}, {Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualHeight})]"
                ToolTip="Expand View">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource TealMidBrush}"
                    Kind="ArrowExpandAll" />
            </Button>
    ...
```

The two labels which show the "MainGrid's" ActualWidth & ActualHeight both have positive numbers showing `415` and `660`, respectively. However, when I try to pass those numbers down to the ViewModel via the Caliburn Micro messaging of:

`cm:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action LaunchMirrorView({Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}, {Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualHeight})]"`

What comes into my ViewModel's method always comes in a zero for both of those variables?

```
public void LaunchMirrorView(double actualWidth, double actualHeight)
{
  \\ actualWidth = 0
  \\ actualHeight = 0
}
```

Any ideas on how to pass those sizes correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `{Binding..}` here. Following would be sufficient.

```
[Action LaunchMirrorView(MainGrid.ActualWidth,MainGrid.ActualHeight)]
```

Complete Code

```
<Button Content="Click" 
     cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action LaunchMirrorView(MainGrid.ActualWidth,MainGrid.ActualHeight)]" />
```

This would ensure you receive the parameters ActualWidth and ActualHeight in the ViewModel

Comment: Perfect!  It indeed works  Thanks so much!